# What's the different types of comments in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've started yesterday to use IntelliJ IDEA for java programming, before I was using Eclipse.

I've noticed that there are two types of comments that this software  uses (excluding the classic `//comment here`):

- `/* comment here */`  and it will be displayed in grey
- `/** comment here */` and it will be displayed in green

what is the difference between the two? when should I use one, when the other?

Comment: First one is multi line comment and second is documentation comment.

Comment: When should I use one and when the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*.....*/
```

If you want to comment out multiple line you need to use the multi line comment.

If you want to provide proper documentation to your methods/variables you need to use documentation comments. Since there is a tool which comes with jdk, which will create a documentation for your classes.

```
/**
* This method is used to ...
*/
e.g  public void method()
{
//your logic
}
```

Also you can use it for variable too.

```
/**
* This variable is used for ...
*/
private static int s=99;
```